# What is the meaning of return value of isalpha (at other ctype.h functions)?

Tags: c, ctype, isalpha

The return value of `isalpha()` is `0` if the character is not alphabet and non-zero if its an alphabet. This is also the case for many other `ctype.h` library functions.

Is there any meaning of the return type of this function?
In other words, why not simply return `1` for alphabet characters?
I googled and did not find any answer.

Comment: They’re returning logical boolean values.

Comment: The actual implementation of these functions *or macros* could be something optimal that leads to other values than `1` will be returned. Just use them as boolean functions, since anything non-zero will be "true".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value is not specified, because it might save a few cycles for common implementations to *not* have to set it to 1, if it is not zero. For example, the inequality-test could be implemented as subtraction

```
#define NEQ(a,b) (a-b)
```

If you require to have it return `1` on inequality, you have to do a little more work than only the subtraction. Hence, it might perform better to *not* insist that the functions return 1.

Comment: Even check if register is equal to zero is faster.
Since the Zero Flag is automatically set by most cpu architectures.

Comment: @G.C. This is another implementation detail which  depends on the code context. If you assign the result to a variable (`int isneq = NEQ(a,2)`) , the assembler code is different than if it is only used as a conditional `if (NEQ(a,2)) { ... }`, where indeed checking the zero flag suffices, if the cpu architecture supports it.

Answer (score 0):

It returns an integer value that is nonzero if the character is a letter and zero otherwise. It returns an `int` because that is the default return value from ancient C, and it would require unnecessary code (with little benefit) to restrict the values returned to 0 and 1, considering that these functions are meant to be used in conditions.

You may have also noticed that all of these functions have a name shorter than or as long as eight characters. This is, again, a relic from ancient C. Names of functions could be no longer than 8 characters.

Comment: @klutt How is that?